# The slickGoTo line is causing an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, typeerror

I'm unable to randomize the first slide of a slick carousel (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) by adding the slickGoTo line below.

I get the following Chrome console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick(...).slickGoTo is not a function  
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script-new.js:18)  
  at i (jquery.min.js:2)  
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)  
  at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)  
  at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I'm running the following javascript code:

```
// get the number of slides
var total = $('.slide').length;

// random number
var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * total );

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    arrows:true,
    fade: true,
    slide:".slide",
    pauseOnHover:false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    dots: true
  })
  .slickGoTo(rand); // navigate to random slide
});
```

I'm using jQuery version 1.12.1 and Slick version 1.6.
I want to show a random slide when the page loads but the slide sequence to remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/),

> Methods are called on slick instances through the slick method itself in version 1.4

Meaning you have to use `slick(` with the method name passed as parameter as follow :

```js
$('.slide').slick().slick('slickGoTo', Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="slide">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's got to be just about the worst documentation I've ever seen. +1 for a working solution though.